# Informix on PHP IIS

Tags: php, pdo, informix

i have PHP running on IIS  PHP version 8.2.4

installed Informix CSDK 4.5.0 , using -php_pdo_informix.dll 1.36

getting below error

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_informix.dll' (tried: ext\php_pdo_informix.dll (The specified module could not be found), ext\php_php_pdo_informix.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

I have environmental variable as following

PATH C:\PHP , C:\PHP\ext , C:\Program Files\IBM Informix Client-SDK\bin
INFORMIXDIR C:\Program Files\IBM Informix Client-SDK\

php.ini

```
extension=curl
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
extension=php_pdo_informix.dll
```

i have no idea what i can try next , nothing seem to fix the problem

Comment: Where is `php_pdo_informix.dll` installed?  Is it in one of the directories listed by `PATH`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). Files you specify with `extension=...` need to be in the [`extension_dir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dir). Please provide the value of that setting and also the absolute pathname of `php_pdo_informix.dll` to show whether this matches or not. You can do so by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: What about getting a ProcessMonitor trace (Sysinternals) to check which library fails to load? Could be either your system is missing some of the required libraries (like vc runtime). If you are running under IIS make sure it is set to run in 64-bit mode, and PATH and INFORMIXDIR are both set at system level as IIS may run as a different user (usually the Local System account)